# Standard for typedef'ing

Tags: c, typedef

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I am just wondering is there any standard that should be followed when creating types.

for example:

```
typedef struct date
{
} date_t;
```

I have also seen people put a capital like this:

```
typedef struct date
{
} Date;
```

Or for variables

```
typedef unsigned int Age;
```

or this

```
typedef unsigned int age_t;
```

Is there any standard that should be followed. Personally I prefer post fixing with a _t.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I think the more customary terminology is 'convention' rather than 'standard'. Good question. I think the openssl project for one uses the convention of typedef struct objname_st {...} objname.

Comment: I can't believe the global C community hasn't developed a shared standard for something this elementary after 50-odd years. Almost every other major language has obvious naming & style conventions everyone sticks to because we all understand the value in doing so, whereas you still regularly see people writing C functions without word separators of any kind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much of this comes down to personal preference, with the key being to be consistent (or if you have a company convention, use that).  The following article has some naming guides:

http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~piater/Cours/Coding-Style/

Note that it switches the '_t' portion:

```
typedef struct node_t {
  void *content;
  struct node_t *next;
} Node;

typedef enum season_t { SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, WINTER } Season;
```

There was an earlier discussion on C naming conventions here:

[What are the most common naming conventions in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722112/what-are-the-most-common-naming-conventions-in-c)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the Node as the tag name, and node_t as the type? Thanks.

Comment: Given that '_t' is reserved for POSIX, I would suggest not using '_t' at all and coming up with a naming convention that makes sense to you (for example, see @casablanca's answer).  I only quoted from the article, which is only an opinion.

Answer (score 42):

If you are working on a platform that follows POSIX standards you should be aware that any identifier ending in `_t` is reserved for POSIX defined types so it is not advisable to follow the same convention for your own types.

Answer (score 14):

You may just simply use

```
typedef struct toto toto;
```

1. The `struct toto` (tag) and the
   `typedef` name `toto` (identifier)
   are in different C "namescopes" so
   they are compatible, but they point to the same type in the end.
2. As an extra bonus this is also
   compatible with C++, which usually
   implicitly has such a `typedef`.
3. As another bonus this inhibits to
   declare a variable `toto` which can
   be quite confusing at times.

Comment: I'm glad I scrolled down and had to face-palm myself for not directly thinking about this.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is any "standard" naming convention. In fact, they vary so wildly between projects (and also between other languages like C++ or Java) that I've personally adopted camelCase in all languages.

I always define my structures through `typedef`, so I just use whatever name I would have given it otherwise (this is also what the Win32 API does). In case I need a self-referencing structure, I prefix an `_` to the raw struct's name:

```
typedef struct _Node {
  _Node *next;
} Node;
```

Comment: Of course for some reason the C# and .NET convention seems to be capitalize the first letter of method and field names.

Comment: Names with a leading underscore followed by a capital letter or another underscore are reserved. (Names with a leading underscore following by a lowercase letter might be reserved depending on the scope; easier to just avoid leading underscores.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Answer (score 4):

Style is a very personal and highly subjective thing, I strongly urge you to just use whatever you like, or whatever conventions are used in your organization.

Comment: But, conventions evolve based on experience. Why not try to leverage that experience?

Answer (score 3):

Follow what the rest of the people do for your project so everything stays consistent. Otherwise they're both acceptable technically.

Answer (score 1):

In general most languages allow the use of SentenceCase for non-standardized classes or types. I find this is the best practise, and in languages that allow it, additionally use namespaces or modules to prevent clashes. In languages that don't (such as C), a prefix where necessary never goes astray. To use a multi-language example for something I'm currently working on:

```
C: typedef uint32_t CpfsMode;
C++: namespace Cpfs { typedef uint32_t Mode; }
Python: cpfs.Mode = int
```