# The meaning of _t in intptr_t

Tags: c++, c, nginx

i want to know what is intptr_t ?
what means of (_t) ? is it the first word of (tree) or what?

for example in nginx web server , what is ngx_xx_t (_t) ?

what is diffrent between (ngx_xx_t ) and (ngx_xx_s) ? what is (_t) and (_s) ? (Abbreviation)

Comment: (t)ypedef or (t)ypename ?

Comment: Not sure but a lot of things use it. Even the unicode on windows uses `_T("somestring here");` I'd say it just means `type` or `typedef`

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the suffix of `_t` refers to `typedef`, and `_s` to a structure. There is no difference to the compiler, but for the benefit of users reading the code. This was once a common practice to apply such suffixes, but is now discouraged due to conflicts with POSIX & basic human confusion. Other similar discussions

- [Standard for typedef'ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538170/standard-for-typedefing)
- [Naming scheme for typedefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186072/naming-scheme-for-typedefs)
- [What does a type followed by _t (underscore-t) represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)
- [struct (C programming language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)

Example:

```c
// Discouraged
struct foo_s {
    int bar;
};
typdef struct foo_s foo_t;

// Friendly
typedef struct foo_struct {
    int bar;
} foo_type;
```