# Understanding part of an algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

Below is a part of an algorithm i was given to use for a project, but as it's my first time to use an algorithm i don't understand the following lines. Please will need your help.

```
For i=1 to n do
     t[i] .mark <-- 0
     t[i] .num <-- -1
End
```

Comment: i don't understand the meaning of the dot

Comment: This isn't C and it makes little sense (without additional context). The best interpretation is that this is *pseudocode* for initializing an array of structs.

Comment: I consider it pseudo code for "in a loop from 1 to n, set the correspondingly indexed member of array named t, struct member named mark to 0, struct member named num to 1". It implies a data structure of array of structs. I assume that you should have learned those things in the course and you can now start coding.

Comment: If I am right, it leaves to wonder what should happen to t[0]. It is not one of those teachers who count 1 and up, is it?

Comment: @Yunnosch That might be intentional if the point of the homework problem is to translate something from pseudocode to C. Pseudocode is often 1-based, and an important skill is to be able to translate from 1-based pseudocode to 0-based code.

Comment: @JohnColeman Agreed. So adding an "assuming counting from 1 and array indices from 0" and then filling from 0 would demonstrate that ability by making clear a) noticed b) made intentional assumption as meaningful as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "t" seems to be an array of objects, and "mark" and "num" are properties of the object. 
This may help you:
[From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: Please don't pressure the asker into accepting an answer just 10 minutes after asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

This pseudo code can be translated to `C`

**Use `struct`**

```
struct cm{
    int mark;
    int num;
};


#define N 10

int main(void)
{

    struct cm t[N];

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        t[i].mark = 0;
        t[i].num = -1;
    }   

    //print your struct elements field
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%d: %d, %d\n",i ,t[i].mark, t[i].num);
    }

}
```

We have an array of `struct` because of we need each element of it  have two field of data (i.e. mark,num).

`struct cm t[N];` define a `N` length array of structure `cm`.

In loop we assign to each field of array elements proper values.

For more readability you can use `typedef` instead of using `struct` to define your desire data structure in this case.
[typedef vs struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

**Use `typedef`**

```
typedef struct typecm{
    int mark;
    int num;
}typecm;


#define N 10

int main(void)
{

    typecm s[N];

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        s[i].mark = 0;
        s[i].num = -1;
    }   

    //print values
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%d: %d, %d\n",i ,s[i].mark, s[i].num);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `I < 9` should be `I < 10` (or even better, `I < n`). It's also unusual to use uppercase letters for variables in C.

Comment: I accept use n instead of hard coding 10. (9 is wrong thanks for catch my error). But i want to use uppercase letters for variables. suppose we have i,j as index, as these are very similar, I want to use I,K,M as loop iterator. I grab this idea from https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-t_ez3e3VAhUErRQKHdvwBMMQFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F12394453-art-of-programming-contest&usg=AFQjCNFZLwdf6IRDpNhKlzJdCViHEnlpRg

Comment: Whichever coding convention works for you, it's fine, but keep in mind that programming for contests usually has quite opposite goals than programming for maintainability. I would never use the same casing for `struct` names (like `M`) and variables (like `I`), because casing is usually meant to differentiate the class of the identifier (struct, function, local variable, global variable). You could also argue that `I` is similar to `T`.

Comment: It seems true, and you say i must use small letters for all variable in `C` and only use capitals for Globals, constants, and etc

Comment: No, not specifically, people use various conventions (e.g. `struct SomeStruct`, `int variable = 5`, `void do_something(void)` or `void 
doSomething()`, caps are usually macros like `#define MAX_NUM 5`, etc). As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1722112/69809), for example, everyone has a different idea, but is always to differentiate different symbols *somehow* (but variables are almost universally lowercase in all the sources I've seen so far). But again, if your company has a certain coding standard, it's what you should use to make all code consistent.

Comment: @Groo first is my edition on post correct both in logical and coding style. second if you suggest to use special coding style for `C`, i am not restricted to use some special style, i code for hobby and learn.